# Getting the {searchTerms} on the receiving end of OpenSearch?

Tags: php, parameters, opensearch

I have implemented `OpenSearch` on a website, but the idea is to receive the resulting parameter and then use it to forward to another service. Something like:

- My opensearch.xml has the URL such as mywebsite/search&q={searchTerms}
- When I reach mywebsite/search, I need to verify if "q" exists and proceed

I'm trying to print all `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables, and "q" is nowhere to be seen.

How can I test if `{searchTerms}` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mywebsite/search&q={searchTerms}
```

the url should be

```
mywebsite/search?q={searchTerms}
```

or you are not sending valid query parameters then q should be accessible in `$_GET['q']`

Comment: I was looking everywhere except the obvious place ... Thanks!